# jQuery File Upload fails on large files

Tags: jquery-file-upload, blueimp

I am trying to use Blueimp jQuery File Upload and it works great with small files.  If  try to upload anything greater than 50mb it fails and I get an error 'Empty file upload result'.

I have seen lots of responses to questions from people getting the same error but they seem to get it despite the file uploading correctly or the code corrections suggested don't seem to apply to the code that is now supplied with the plugin.

The FAQ suggests that there is a server side restriction on file size but I have asked my host to increase it to 1GB and they have confirmed they have done this.  I do not have permission to overwrite the php.ini as suggested in the FAQ, I just get a server error.

Has anyone else had this problem and if so how was it resolved?

I am using PHP.

Comment: Create a file with `<?php phpinfo();` and tell which is the output of max_post_size

Comment: thank you, it still shows as the max file upload as 50m.  Guess I must have a php.ini lurking somewhere with this value

Comment: In the phpinfo you can see which `php.ini` files are being loaded. Some hosting providers allow to add custom php configuration lines in different ways, sometimes in Apache's `.htaccess`. Try all possibilities or better ask again to your host provider to set this field to 1 GB too.

Comment: I had the same issue and the problem was the limitation of "Maximum HTTP POST size" not "Maximum file upload size".